# jQuery radio button checked, else statement not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, radio-button

I want an input to change its styles (add background color) when checked. This is working, however, the else statement to remove the background color when the input radio type isn't checked is not working.

Have tried various different ways but cannot get the else statement to fire when you click a different input.

HTML:

```
<tr style="color:white;">
<td id="test" style="background-color:rgb(153, 117, 82);" value="1">
<label><input type="radio" name="c0" class="c0" value="10" onclick="output();" id="t"/>1</label>
</td>
</tr>

<tr style="color:white;">
<td style="background-color: rgb(255, 57, 57);">
<label><input type="radio" name="c0" class="c0" value="20" onclick="output();" id="t"/>2</label>
</td>
```

JS:

```
$('input#t').on("click", function() {
if ($("input#t").is(':checked')) {
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
} 
    else {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
}
});
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/Not_A_Fax_Machine/pen/zzRMNZ/

Comment: The problem is because you have two elements with the same `id` attribute - they ***must*** be unique.

Comment: have also tried - $('input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox]').on("click", function() {

 
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    } else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
    }

});   - therefore with no ID's, to no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you have two elements with the same `id` attribute - they ***must*** be unique.

To fix the problem use a class to group the radio buttons, then use the `this` keyword to reference the element within the `change` event handler. Try this:

```js
$('.t').on("change", function() {
  $('label').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('active', this.checked);
  // output();
});
```

```css
tr {
  color: white;
}

td.foo {
  background-color: rgb(153, 117, 82);
}

td.bar {
  background-color: rgb(255, 57, 57);
}

.active {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="foo">
      <label><input type="radio" name="c0" class="t c0" value="10" />1</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bar">
      <label><input type="radio" name="c0" class="t c0" value="20" />2</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note the removal of the inline styles, which should be avoided.

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately.

Comment: Can you expand on that. What does/does not happen? Any errors in the console? As you can see from the snippet above, it works fine given your sample code in the question

Comment: User error! Thanks a lot, been stuck on this for ages!